# Function to return the stripped whitespace of a string

Tags: python, string, whitespace, strip

Is there an existing function in Python that works like `.strip()`/`.lstrip()`/`.rstrip()` do, but instead, returns the stripped whitespace rather than the resulting stripped string?

Namely:

```
test_str = '\n\ttext goes here'
test_str.lstrip() # yields 'text goes here'
test_str.lwhite() # yields '\n\t'
```

Where `.white()`, `.lwhite()`, and `.rwhite()` are the functions that I'm hoping exist. Otherwise I'll have to make do with regex and captured groups:

```
^(\s*).*(\s*)$    for .white()
^(\s*)            for .lwhite()
(\s*)$            for .rwhite()
```

To give a better example, Python has `.strip()` methods that remove the whitespace at the start and end of a given string and return the stripped string. Same with Python's `.lstrip()` and `.rstrip()` methods for just the beginning and ends respectively.

I'm looking for a way to return the whitespace that was stripped off the ends of the string. So for a string like the following...

```
sample = '\n\t this string\t is \n \ta sample\t!\n'
```

...I'd want `'\n\t '` returned for a beginning version, `'\n'` returned for an ending version, or both in a list returned for the full version.

Thanks all!

Comment: Are you ok with using itertools? o.0 or is that heresy?

Comment: @Shashank: dropwhile and takewhile are simple enough to code them yourself even if he says no. :)

Comment: @Shashank The original goal was to get this done while importing as few modules as possible, but at that point I suppose it would be more trouble that this is worth unless there's already a function that does this. You've perked my interest regarding itertools though. How would this be done with that module?

Comment: I think the most efficient way would be use `itertools.takewhile` in combination with `reversed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops, I just realized you meant strip instead of split, so here's an [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) solution:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def lstripped(s):
    return ''.join(takewhile(str.isspace, s))

def rstripped(s):
    return ''.join(reversed(tuple(takewhile(str.isspace, reversed(s)))))

def stripped(s):
    return lstripped(s), rstripped(s)
```

The polyfill for [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) is the following:

```
def takewhile(predicate, iterable):
    # takewhile(lambda x: x<5, [1,4,6,4,1]) --> 1 4
    for x in iterable:
        if predicate(x):
            yield x
        else:
            break
```

Comment: That's actually really nifty! Will definitely keep this at the back of my head since I'm not sure which I'll be using at this point. Performance-wise, how do you think this would fare compared to the regex solution?

Comment: @lostguru Time-complexity-wise, this is about as efficient as it can get since both takewhile and reversed are fast iterators that stop ASAP instead of processing the whole string. So it has basically the same time complexity as a non-greedy `re.search` solution that stops as soon as it finds a match. But time complexity is not the same as performance...`re` is a beast of a module that is optimized to work on strings only, while itertools has to be able to process all kinds of iterables.   You're probably going to see better performance from `re` but I would benchmark it to be sure.

Comment: Got it, definitely good to know. Will give this a shot tomorrow when I'm on the working computer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably taking your words literally - but if you want to get only the whitespace in your string, then isn't list comprehension the way to go ?

```
In [112]: x
Out[112]: '\n\ttext goes here'

In [113]: ''.join([i for i in x if not i.isalnum()]).replace(" ",'')
Out[113]: '\n\t'
```

Comment: Close haha, to goal is to just return `'\n\t'` rather than `'\n\t  '`.

Comment: Updated. This seems to do the job. :)

Comment: Bad example on my part, sorry. Python has `.strip()` methods that remove the whitespace at the start and end of a given string and return the stripped string. Same with Python's `.lstrip()` and `.rstrip()` methods for just the beginning and ends respectively. I was looking for a way to return the whitespace that was stripped off the ends of the string.

So for a string like `sample = '\n\t this string\t is \n \ta sample\t!\n'` I'd want `'\n\t '` returned for a beginning version, `'\n'` returned for an ending version, or both in a list returned for the full version.

Comment: Ah ha. You should put this in the question as well.

Comment: I thought mentioning `.strip()` would be enough, but now that I do have the better example, I'll add it to the question.